# JQuery File Upload with Ruby on Rails/brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was interested in JQuery File Uploader on Ruby on Rails and tried to use [this application](https://github.com/banditj/fily/tree/no-asset-pipeline#readme)m and [this one](https://github.com/jalagrange/bootstrap_uploader) 


I have made a new rails project with "rails new fily" and have copied and pasted all files in my fily-folder that they have in this application. I run `bundle install` and `rake db:migrate` but by opening `localhost:3000/picture` the only thing that I saw was: `[]`, brackets and nothing more. What can be the reason?


In terminal I see following:

```
Started GET "/pictures" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-21 23:21:13 +0200
  Processing by PicturesController#index as HTML
  Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" 
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
[2012-10-21 23:21:14] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

I would be grateful if somebody helps me

PS. I have found as well some very strange hidden file there:

```
 .rvmrc
```

with a content:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@fily
```

What should that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .rvmrc file is used by RVM, the Ruby Version Manager, which allows multiple versions of Ruby to coexist on a machine, and allows you to specify which ones to use. The .rvmrc tells RVm to use the specified version of ruby, although it seems to me that the person who made that git repo used his own compiled from source. I don't think deleting it will bring any harm.

Looking at the code, (haven't got ruby on this machine yet so I can't test it to be sure), it seems as though you shouldn't be accessing /pictures. Instead, just access / (which calls and renders the pictures#new controller).